# assembly wrong expected value on register

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

The C version of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char S2[] = {65, 108, 111, 32, 123, 103, 97, 108, 101, 114, 97, 125, 33, 0};

int main (void) 
{
    char *pc = S2;
    int count;

    for (count = 0; *pc; count++)
    {
       *pc++;     
    }

    printf ("%d", count);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The intention is to calculate and print the length of the S2 array, excluding the '0'.
Followed by a newline.

The assembly code:

```
.data
S2: .byte   65, 108, 111, 32, 123, 103, 97, 108, 101, 114, 97, 125, 33, 0
Sf: .string "%d"        # format string for printf

.text
.globl  main
main:
/****** do no change, prologue !!!! */
        push    %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ebx        
/*******/

        movl    $S2, %ecx   
        movl    $0, %ebx    

L1: 
        cmpl    $0, (%ecx)       
        je      after       
        incl    %ecx           
        incl    %ebx            
        jmp     L1              
after:  
        movl    %ebx, %eax  

/****** do not change - prints the value of %eax !!!! */
/* may crash the value of %eax          ******/
        pushl   %ecx
        pushl   %edx
        pushl   %eax
        pushl   $Sf
        cal     printf  
        addl    $8, %esp
        popl    %edx
        popl    %ecx
/*******/

        movl    $0, %eax        /* return value */

/****** do not change - end!!!! */
        popl    %ebx        
        movl    %ebp, %esp
        popl    %ebp
        ret         
/*******/
```

First I'm not sure about how to insert the new printf. By adding a .string "\n" in Sf it changes the count value. If I create a Sf2, not sure if I must create a whole new printf call as it is in the 'do not change' box or just insert Sf2 on it.

In any cases I'm getting weird values like 16, 17 or 18, although the length of S2 is 13.
Thought it could be something about the size (byte) of the elements and the instructions being long. But changing that only gives me more headache.

So, why the wrong values?
The best way to do the new printf?

Comment: Your guess about the item size was right. You have bytes so you should use a byte sized compare, that is `cmpb` not `cmpl`.

Comment: In the C code, `*pc++;` should just say `pc++;`, the `*` does nothing.

Comment: @interjay yeah it should be just `pc++` but the `*` does do something ;) It just doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @Jester it doesn't do anything in this case (except for confusing people) as `++` has higher precedence, and the result of dereferencing is ignored.

Comment: Yes, that's what it does - it dereferences. The fact that the value is ignored and that the pointer is valid is why it doesn't matter in this case. As I said, I agree that it should be just `pc++`.

Comment: Thanks @Jester the first issued was solved. If you can explain why exactly I'm getting 18 from the compl, that would be great. The extension shouldn't change the values or anything. Or... ?
interjay your comment was right. Anyways the * would ++ the value in the pointer briefly, that's all.

Still waiting the answer about the printf.

Comment: `cmpl` looks for 4 consecutive `0` bytes. Depending on where that is found (probably after all your data) it will return different length. Not sure what you are asking regarding the `printf`, you can just change the format string to `%d\n` and be done with the task as described.

Comment: WHy make the code complicated?  the size of the S2 array can be directly calculated by count = sizeof(S2)/sizeof(char) -1;  even better would be count = strlen(S2);

Comment: changing the first printf format string to "%d\n" would not change the generated code any (it will change the contents of the .const value sf but that will not change the code any)

Comment: This line:     *pc++; in the 'for' loop seems to be the main problem.  I.E. the code wants to increment the pointer, not the value where the pointer points.  SO write the line as pc++;

Comment: this line: 'for (count = 0; *pc; count++)' is using the *pc as the stay in loop relational comparison.  it would be better to use 'for (count = 0; *pc != 0; count++)'

Comment: True @Jester. I was with that line of thought because of this previous similar code http://ideone.com/wBa2AW There I couldn't do that with the `%c, the `\n` stayed within the loop. What do do here? Also, if I use `cmpb` shouldn't I use `movb` and `%cl` (or `%ch`) too? I'm already getting `(.text+0x5): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against .data collect2: ld returned 1 exit status` and then `(%cl) is not a valid base/index expression` errors but, why that's not the case?

Comment: You only need to use byte size when accessing the chars in your string. For moving around the string's address you need to use the size of the pointer.

Comment: Thanks @Jester, last one: In this http://ideone.com/8I55SR code, I originally used `%eax` in `line 31`, but by doing so, I was getting weird values on the output, especifically `65, -96, 121, 44`. The reads on the array are correct, I tested it. However if I use another register like `%esi` and then `movl` from him to `%eax` - `line 42` - it all goes well. Why is that? I choosed `%eax` in the first place cause I knew it would be used by `printf` later.

Comment: Read your own comment on line `44`: `printf` will destroy `eax` (it's used as the return value).

Comment: Not my comment, teacher's code. Will or may? `printf` definition or `popl %eax` absence?